# remove rqt left corner 'x - []' icons

Tags: rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I plan to use rqt on a raspberry touch panel which is apparently smaller than a pc. I'd like to realize two modifications,

1. Let the rqt automatically fit to the size of the raspberry screen once launched from terminal.
2. Given that a launch file is used to start the rqt and fill it to the size of the screen, I want to remove the icons 'close, minimize and maximize' on the left corner of rqt because they look redundent to these simliar icons on the raspberry display.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270864/remove-rqt-left-corner-%27x---%5B%5D%27-icons/) by [Helen HOU](https://answers.ros.org/users/28362/helen-hou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The icons in the top left corner of the window are coming from the window manager. Those are not specific to rqt / ros / qt but the window manager you use on your system. Depending on what platform you are that might be Unity, Gnome, etc. Maybe that helps you direct your search.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2017-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0